# Object is not being saved in the shared Preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, gson

I am working on an update details of an object in an android project using rest with retrofit2.0. After I call the edit method I get a positive response, that my changes are being saved but while saving it in the shared prefernces and trying to get it from it I get the old unchanged data and checking in the database its the old data (the rest service work just fine I tested it with postman).

this is my code :

```
           public void editUser(){
    user.setNom(nom);
    user.setPrenom(prenom);
    user.setAdresse(adresse);
    user.setTel(telephone);
    apiService = RestService.createService(SolarAPIService.class);
    Call<String> call = apiService.editUser(nom,prenom,adresse,telephone,user.getIdUser());
    call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
            if(response.body().isEmpty()){
                Snackbar.make(layout, "OOps modification non autorisée !", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                save(user);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
            Snackbar.make(layout, "OOps!!!!!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}
```

This is where the edit is being called

```
              valider.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                editUser();

            phoneView.setText(""+user.getTel());
            adrView.setText(user.getAdresse());
            nomV.setText(user.getNom()+" "+user.getPrenom());
            mailV.setText(user.getLogin());
            getUserShrdPref();
            Snackbar.make(layout, "Changement effectué avec sucess !!"+user.getAdresse(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
    });
```

And this is the save and getSharedPrefernces

```
         public void save(User user) {
    mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(user);
    prefsEditor.putString("user", json);
    prefsEditor.commit();
}

     public void getUserShrdPref() {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = mPrefs.getString("user", "");
    user = gson.fromJson(json, User.class);
}
```

The problem is there is no exceptions or crashes nothing at all, I can't figure out the error.

Comment: Hello, have you tried using prefsEditor.apply(); instead of prefsEditor.commit(); I use apply when I use retrofit.

Comment: Show the `getPreferences` method

Comment: its the `getUserShrdPref()` method

Comment: Could be a race condition.  Where is nom, prenom, address, etc being set?

Comment: @MeknessiHamida Show us the `editUser` method.

Comment: @kailoon you are right its a race condition. Its the matter where those fields are set.

Comment: if(response.body().isEmpty()){
                Snackbar.make(layout, "OOps modification non autorisée !", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                save(user);

            }

you are saving user here but i did not understand what are you updating.

Comment: I am updating the user object in the sharedpreferences after the sucess of the update webservice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a race condition. Check where nom, prenom, and those fields are set. =)

Comment: Just to trouble you to check once more with me, now the data is being really saved in the database but not in the shared Preferences ? Any idea ?

Comment: Hmm. Do you really need to call getUserShrdPref(); in onClick(), because the user instance should already have the latest data? It might be what EKN is saying about it being a long process and the getUserShrdPref() is being called before the commit() completes. You only really need to call getUserShrdPref() if the user instance doesn't have the latest data.

Comment: I have taken in consideration your remarks, just one more question if its ok to trouble you, since the shared prefernces data is being modified inside an activity, on pressing the back button, the user is going back to a fragment, I would like to know where in the fragment lifecycle am going back to , what method is being called ?

Comment: This depends on your implementation. Debug and place breakpoints or debug log statements should help. Cheers.

Comment: well actually am going for the default implementation nothing special, but the come and go between the activity lifecycle and fragment lifecycle confuses me, thank you anyway @kailoon you ve been quite helpfull

Answer (score 0):

Json to string conversion is a time taking process. As per your code updation of shared preference is just below the json conversion code. There is a chance to execute shared pref updation before json conversion.

So the better solution is, use async task for this conversion and update shared preference in the onPostExcecute(). This may solve your issue. Please try.

Refer link: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html